# Javax empty integer field validation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, spring-data-jpa

My app uses javax validation for the salary field, which is int. With what annotation should I use it, to avoid the error message like that

> Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to
>   required type 'int' for property 'salary'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

My current implementation looks like this:

```
@Column(name = "salary", nullable = false)
@NotNull(message= "salary may not be empty")
@Range(min = 1)
private int salary;
```

I know that I can not use NotBlank for a int field, that leads to an error. How can I display the message "salary may not be empty" instead of the exception above, if the "string" is empty? Thanks

Comment: change the type from primitive type 'int' to Wrapper class 'Integer'. It will work

Comment: You can check @NotEmpty.

Comment: Thank you, I know it. Is there another solution?

Comment: You can use Pattern also like ...@Pattern(regexp = "[\\s]*[0-9]*[1-9]+",message="msg")

Comment: @Pattern can't be applied for Integer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suggest you to use the object type `Integer` which can hold the null value itself.

```
@Column(name = "salary", nullable = false)
@NotNull(message= "salary may not be empty")
@Range(min = 1)
private Integer salary;
```

The above secures there will be always the `salary` input that has a value and it's equal or greater than 1.

Comment: Would someone give me a hint what makes my answer get a downvote? These anonymous downvotes are really not helpful, I don't know how to fix a mistake if there is any.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Column(name = "salary", nullable = false)
@Range(min = 1, message= "salary may not be empty or null")
private int salary;
```

In @Range we can also mention message. It means salary will be 1 or greater than 1 it will not null or empty.

Answer (score 0):

Set this to your web deployment descriptor file, web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>
        javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL
    </param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

If that field is included in another class, such as:

```
public static class Employee {
    @Column(name = "salary", nullable = false)
    @NotNull(message= "salary may not be empty")
    @Range(min = 1)
    private int salary;
}
```

You also need to make sure use @Valid for instances of Employee:

```
@Valid @NotNull
public Employee someEmployee;
```